# Confirmation before running a Grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a task in Gruntfile.js which can potentially wipe my project and I want to protect it with a "Are you sure you want to run this task?" question before running it, just to be safe. Something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('install', 'Run this only once when starting a project!', function() {
    console.log('Are you sure? Y/n:');

    // If yes, continue with task
    grunt.task.run('copy_install');
});
```

But I don't know how to make it wait for keyboard input and read the input. Could not find this documented either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it! You will regret this!

Grunt is a build tool and you grunt script should only be able to wipe what it created. No matter what the reasoning behind your current state is, change it. Use the tool for what is was meant to do, not for wiping stuff you dont want to lose.

Comment: I see your point, I'm still thinking if I should keep this "install" script or not. I'm making a template for wordpress plugin (I make a lot of plugins) and I'm trying to automate every repeatable task, including generating a template WP plugin in the wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ folder. Which means if I run this script twice it would override any changes that I made to the template that it copied.

Comment: However I think I found a workaround - it checks to see if the path exists and if it does, it just quits the task. Now there is no way to overwrite anything.

Comment: So technically, the script can no longer delete anything, so I think I will keep it like this. I just made up my mind, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [grunt-prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-prompt) or [grunt-confirm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-confirm).